# Auto generating metadata classes for Entity Framework

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, xval, model-validation

I am considering using xVal for validation of Entity Framework classes in a MVC application. This involves writing metadata classes as explained in details by Graham O'Neale (http://goneale.com/2009/03/04/using-metadatatype-attribute-with-aspnet-mvc-xval-validation-framework).

I am wondering if there's a way to auto generate such metadata classes using the metadata from the SQL database (for example: not null fields will have [Required] class attribute.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use Code Smith tool www.codesmithtools.com (there is a free version if I remember correctly)

Answer (score 1):

I wrote an application that will read an existing database and then generate a Data Annotation Class for every table (excluding aspnet_* and VersionInfo).

http://pfsolutions-mi.com/Product/MetaDataClassGenerator

Comment: I like this app! Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

In EF 4, [you can easily customize the code generation via a T4 template](http://blogs.msdn.com/efdesign/archive/2009/01/22/customizing-entity-classes-with-t4.aspx).

Comment: This requires Visual Studio 2010. I only have Visual Studio 2008.

Comment: There are T4 producers for VS 2008, too. But in your shoes I'd rather make a custom validation provider which understands EF attributes. Actually, I'd *really* rather use edit models. But that's not what you asked....

Comment: I dont mind changing the validation provider. Which validation provider which understands EF attributes? or how to use edit models?

Comment: Validation providers: You'd have to write one. But it's not hard: http://bradwilson.typepad.com/blog/2010/01/why-you-dont-need-modelmetadataattributes.html Edit models: This just means you create a type for the sole purpose of binding your form, and project your entity onto that, instead of binding directly to the entity.