# How to keep properties attributes inserted into auto-generated files in ASP.NET MVC

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-5

I use ASP.NET MVC 5 and Entity Framework 6. So I have generated some files under *.tt

I would like to keep attributes that i inserted into those files because I have created many pages automatically based on Entity Framework classes.

But when I update Entity Framework model from the database I loose everything that I inserted.

So my question is how to keep it from deleting?

> //------------------------------------------------------------------------------ //  //     This code was generated from a template. //
>   //     Manual changes to this file may cause unexpected behavior in
>   your application. //     Manual changes to this file will be
>   overwritten if the code is regenerated. // 
>   //------------------------------------------------------------------------------

```
namespace MyWebSIte.DataModel
{
    using System;
    using System.Collections.Generic;
    using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;

    public partial class ItemMovement
    {
        public System.Guid ID { get; set; }

        [DataType(DataType.DateTime)]  <---- I would like to keep it.
        [DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:dd/MM/yyyy}", ApplyFormatInEditMode = true)]
        [Display(Name = "Fecha")]
        public System.DateTime? Changed { get; set; }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The generated class ItemMovement is a partial class. 

This allows you to write a second partial class which is marked with the necessary data annotations. 

 In your case the partial class ItemMovement would look like this:

```
   namespace MyWebSIte.DataModel
    {
        using System;
        using System.Collections.Generic;
        using System.ComponentModel;
        using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;

        [MetadataType(typeof(ItemMovementMetaData))]
        public partial class ItemMovement
        {
            public System.Guid ID { get; set; }        
            public System.DateTime? Changed { get; set; }
        }

        public partial class ItemMovementMetaData {

            [DataType(DataType.DateTime)]
            [DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:dd/MM/yyyy}", ApplyFormatInEditMode = true)]
            [Display(Name = "Fecha")]
            public System.DateTime? Changed { get; set; }   

            //....................
        }
    }
```

Comment: Could we generate it automatically in ASP.NET MVC?

Comment: How would you have them generated automatically, if you have to provide the annotations manually?

Comment: You can't generate them dynamically you  have to write them manually

Comment: I mean all entity classes under *.tt generated by Entity Framework but I am asking if it possible to generate MetadataCalsses the same way like we do it in RIA Services.

Comment: Your answer is correct but I found a similar one http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2229716/auto-generating-metadata-classes-for-entity-framework  and over there I also found this app http://pfsolutions-mi.com/Product/MetaDataClassGenerator that does all job I need to do manually.

Comment: Is this still up to date?

Answer (score 2):

Those files are not meant to be edited manually. You should take advantage of the fact that those classes are `partial` and can be "extended". Take a look at [Metadata classes](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee707339(v=vs.91).ASPX), they will allow you to annotate properties.

Comment: It is for RIA Services. I dont use it. Are you sure we can use it for ASP.NET MVC?

Comment: Frankly, I only focused on the part which shows how to use Metadata classes. The principal is the same - you create a metadata class, you create a partial class for entity type and mark it with attribute. Take a look here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/4916085/6804888

Comment: Of course there is a second option which involves creating `interface` for the entity and marking the properties in it with annotations, but it is also described in the SO link I provided.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the codefirst which gives u max control over your models and dbcontext.

Step1 : Create a codefirst model using the existing database.
[codefirst model using the existing database](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ESiVM.png)

Step 2: now type enable-migrations in the package manager console

Step 3: You use the (db)context and the model generated from the database table.
       make changes to your model

Step 4: type add-migration [some name to identify the migration]  in the package manager console

Step 5: check the generated migration file.

Step 6: type update-database in the package manager console

Now your changes are updated to the database. From now on you can us the codefirst approach to handle the changes to your database.